# Applying directives during dynamic component initialization

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using the `ComponentFactoryResolver` to dynamically create components.

```
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(FooComponent);
const component = this.templateRoot.createComponent(factory).instance;
```

Is it possible to conditionally apply directives here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported way to apply directives is to add markup to a components template statically.

You can compile a component dynamically if you need to do that at runtime.

See for example [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)